# Use of Global Model in ios APp

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I am designing an app which manages a tank of hot water. The app makes RESTful API calls to a service to;

1. Obtain a profile of temperature at various layers in the tank.
2. Allow a user to work with a timer (like an immersion timer) custom control to set times to turn on/off heating elements.

So, as a first cut, I have two tabs in a nav controller; 
1. A graphic, showing a picture of the tank, graduated to show temperature.
2. A custom control, like commercial domestic timers, with two concentric rings, allowing the user to point, and drag 30 minute slots to set times for heating elements.

I have both custom views working well. I'm afraid to say I'm stuck on a very simple point - even after reading all of Apple's ios docs, and would love some help.

The data server (A BeagleBone running embedded Linux) implements 2 sets of RESTful APIs, one dealing with tank temps, and the other set to read and to update timers.

1. Is it best to start the App with a view controller which instantiates a model, who issues the APIs, and displays "Loading...", then populate a single application wide data model.
2. Have each view controller (The image of the tank, and the timer controller) to populate their own (separate) model?
3. And the big question for me (despite years of working in Smalltalk, C++, Java...) what is the recommended way to ;

   - instantiate a view controller
   - load / display a view with a "busy"spinner if the model hasn't loaded

My app isn't complicated enough for GCD, or indeed KVO. This is basically, a "show a view, call a web service to read the data", "modify the data", "call a web service to replace the data"

Basically, I believe my question is, when a view comes on screen, what is best practice to determine that the controller has a model, or has a model which is still loading data?

Sorry for the long winded question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a very good question, about a very common task in an mobile app. My suggestions are

1. Since your two tabs really have no common data, the problem simply boils down to "how to initialize a view controller with remote data".
2. If user can't use your app without remote data,

   - simply show a loading view in [vc viewDidLoad], and start fetching data from server asynchronously; your vc should implement NSURLConnectionDelegate to listen to call back
   - when data is successfully fetched from server, dismiss the loading view, and render the data to user
   - if data fetch failed (due to bad network or server downtime), show alert view to user, and retry the data fetching; if fetching fails for several times, tell user to try again later
   - you can make the loading view more beautiful, to provide a better user experience; note the loading view should cover all the buttons/controls, so user can't mess up your app state during data fetching
3. If user can use your app without remote data, it's another story. You shouldn't use a loading view in that case, and should silently fetch data in background. Since this does not seem to be your case, I will not complicate the answer by this case.

Comment: Thank you, a clear answer, and it makes sense to me. So, this is what I am doing now. Can you tell me if, in your opinion it's a little over-engineered, or OK:

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten the hang of editing in these wee boxes yet. When my view starts to display, it asks the ViewController for modelState, and then either; 1. Displays a spinner (state=loading), or 2. if state=dataLoaded calls the ViewController :: getData, and renders the data. Does this sound OK to you?

Comment: Actually, please discard the previous comment. I've advanced a bit, and have decided to use a helper class, based on RESTKit to populate the Model, who will then notify the Controller. (Happy Path). But I'd like you to take a look, as I'm uncertain about error conditions, and threading. Would you mind? Do you know if I can post a diagram on here as a comment?

Comment: @Greycon I think you need to "@" me so that I'll receive an email about your comment. As to error handling:
- NSURLConnection handles errors that happen during server request and response
- If server call is successful, your model should process the received data, and determine if there're any unwanted data; if so, generate an NSError, and notify your vc through notification or KVO or block (any mechanism you prefer); then your vc can show alert upon data error. Hope that helped.